# How to import references/citations from Endnote to LaTeX in Vancouver style?

Tags: biblatex, citing

I just want to know how I can import references/citations (I don't know what the correct term is, but for now, I'll stick with reference) from Endnote to a LaTeX document (which I will save as a pdf when I'm done). The references must be in Vancouver style. To illustrate this, here is a picture (in Word) of how it should look like and I would like to have the same output in LaTeX: [image: Vancouver style referencing in Word]

I have read here and there about something called BibLaTeX, but I don't understand it quite. Like, is it a domain in a LaTeX document? Or is it something different than LaTeX? Is it a special editor? Etc...

I am a complete newbie. In fact, I didn't even know that LaTeX existed before I attended an introduction class 2 weeks ago. Now, after attending this class, I know what you can do with LaTeX and I think it is really cool and I'm determined to learning it (with YouTube tutorials or other resources). So with that said, I just want to ask to go a little easy on me with all the technical terms. Like please don't use too difficult terms that new people won't understand. I will of course do the effort to look something up if I don't understand it, but please don't make me read several webpages just to know the meaning of a term.

So to summarize: how can I link LaTeX with Endnote and import references in Vancouver style?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://www.rhizobia.co.nz/latex/convert provides useful guidance on getting from EndNote to BibTeX. In my case, I export from EndNote using the BibTeX export output style. I then import that file into JabRef which I use to maintain all the BibTeX formatting. I then reexport a bib file from JabRef (bibfile.bib), which can be processed using biblatex after referencing the file using \addbibresource{bibfile.bib}. There are a wealth of biblatex examples you can review to get started - see: https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/examples.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) First, you need convert your Endnote database to **BibTeX** format (not to LaTeX). I have not experience with this, but with the `JabRef` program should be <kbd>File</kbd> > <kbd>Import into new database</kbd> > Select <kbd>File of Type</kbd> > <kbd>Refer/Endnote</kbd> and save the new database with the `.bib` extension. Said you named it as `test.bib` (the  default format is BibTeX). Probably, before of saving, you may want set the <kbd>Database encoding</kbd> to <kbd>UTF8</kbd> (in <kbd>File</kbd> ><kbd>Database properties</kbd>).

If you open the `.bib` file with a text editor, it should be some like:

```
% This file was created with JabRef 2.10.
% Encoding: UTF8

@Article{Arbogast2016,
  Title                    = {Can technology save us? The biomechanics of concussion prevention.},
  Author                   = {Arbogast, K.},
  Journal                  = {Journal of Neurotrauma.},
  Year                     = {2016},
  Pages                    = {A4},
  Volume                   = {33}
}

@Article{Hanson2015,
  Title                    = {Effectiveness of a Home-Based Counselling Strategy on Neonatal Care and Survival: A Cluster-Randomised Trial in Six Districts of Rural Southern {Tanzania}},
  Author                   = {Hanson, Claudia and Manzi, Fatuma and Mkumbo, Elibariki and Shirima, Kizito and Penfold, Suzanne and Hill, Zelee and Shamba, Donat and Jaribu, Jennie and Hamisi, Yuna and Soremekun, Seyi and et al.},
  Journal                  = {PLOS Medicine},
  Year                     = {2015},
  Month                    = {Sep},
  Number                   = {9},
  Pages                    = {e1001881},
  Volume                   = {12},
  Editor                   = {Chappell, Lucy C.Editor},
  ISSN                     = {1549-1676},
  Publisher                = {Public Library of Science (PLoS)}
}

@Article{Kroshus26082015,
  Title                    = {Engaging Teammates in the Promotion of Concussion Help Seeking},
  Author                   = {Kroshus, Emily and Garnett, Bernice R. and Baugh, Christine M. and Calzo, Jerel P.},
  Journal                  = {Health Education \& Behavior},
  Year                     = {2016},
  Number                   = {4},
  Pages                    = {442--51},
  Volume                   = {43}
}
```

2) Now, you need make a **LaTeX** document (said `myfile.tex`) with some text, citing these references with `\cite{<key>}`, set the Vancouver style (with    `\bibliographystyle{vancouver}`)  and calling the `.bib` database (`\bibliography{<filename>}` without extension). Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[colorlinks,citecolor=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage[dutch]{babel}
\begin{document}
Omtrent de biomechanica wordt er iets verteld.\cite{Arbogast2016}
Daarnaast zijn er nog twee topics: homa based telecoinselling\cite{Hanson2015}
en concussion help seeking.\cite{Kroshus26082015}
\bibliographystyle{vancouver} 
\bibliography{test} % this call the test.bib file
\end{document}
```

3) Finally, you must compile this document at least with this sequence to solve all cross references:

```
pdflatex myfile
bibtex myfile
pdflatex myfile
pdflatex myfile
```

The result should be this  `myfile.pdf`:

> [image: mwe]

In complex documents you may need more runs of `pdflatex` or more auxiliar programs. Many LaTeX editors can help in this task, making this step --- more o less --- automatically.