# Inserting Bibliography from Endnote to Overleaf

Tags: bibliographies, natbib, overleaf

I am writing my thesis and now I am trying to insert the bibliography in LaTex. I did everything on EndNote, but now I am having difficulties in moving it into the document.

I followed what said in the [overleaf website](https://www.overleaf.com/help/298-can-i-use-overleaf-with-endnote#.WwmarCOQ3OQ), but nothing appears on my document, and it does not give an error either.

The bibliography is: `bibliography_doc_name.bib`. I did not include the extension as explained in the link above.

The code is:

```
\documentclass[11p]{article}

    \usepackage{natbib}

\begin{document}
            ...

    \section{List of references}
    \bibliographystyle{plainnat}
    \bibliography{bibliography_doc_name}

\end{document}
```

Here you can find two of the references in the bibliography_doc_name.bib file:

```
ï»¿@article{RN41,
   author = {Ang, James S.},
   title = {Small Business Uniqueness and the Theory of Financial Management},
   journal = {The Journal of Entrepreneurial Finance},
   volume = {1},
   number = {1},
   pages = {11-13},
   year = {1991},
   type = {Journal Article}
}

@article{RN33,
   author = {Cassar, Gavin},
   title = {The financing of business start-ups},
   journal = {Journal of Business Venturing},
   volume = {19},
   pages = {261-283},
   DOI = {10.1016/S0883-9026(03)00029-6},
   year = {2004},
   type = {Journal Article}
}
```

Can somebody help me?

P.S. I am using the Overleaf version if that could be a problem.

For some reason, if I use either `\cite{}`, `\citep{}` or `\nocite{*}`, this error appears:

[image: Error]

Comment: How do you cite the references? Are you using `natbib` commands like `\citep` or `\citet`?

Comment: If you just want to print all the references at the end of your thesis try `\nocite{*}` after `\section{List of references}`.

Comment: @DG' I tried with `\nocite{*}`, but it does not work. I wrote the references just as text, so I didn't use any of those two commands.

Comment: please make your code compilable: Add `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}` and a part of your `.bib` file, so we can figure out where your problem lies. You can have a look at [this guide for how to prune your code](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3225) for this purpose.

Comment: This MWE won'vt output anything but three dots. There are no citations.

Comment: @Chiara we need (some of) the content of the file called `bibliography_doc_name.bib`

Comment: @DG' I inserted the part of the code that is relevant.

Comment: You have to delte the garbage (`ï»¿`) in your `.bib` file

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/337889 for Endnote to LaTeX. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10474 for what looks like a byte order mark (BOM) ie the non ascii characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `\nocite{*}` to print the contents of your `.bib` file, even if you haven't used any of the citation commands like `\citep` or `\citet`:

```
\documentclass{article}

    \usepackage{natbib}

\begin{document}

    ...

    \nocite{*}
    \bibliographystyle{plainnat}
    \bibliography{bibliography_doc_name}

\end{document}
```

bibliography_doc_name.bib:

```
@article{RN41,
   author = {Ang, James S.},
   title = {Small Business Uniqueness and the Theory of Financial Management},
   journal = {The Journal of Entrepreneurial Finance},
   volume = {1},
   number = {1},
   pages = {11-13},
   year = {1991},
   type = {Journal Article}
}

@article{RN33,
   author = {Cassar, Gavin},
   title = {The financing of business start-ups},
   journal = {Journal of Business Venturing},
   volume = {19},
   pages = {261-283},
   DOI = {10.1016/S0883-9026(03)00029-6},
   year = {2004},
   type = {Journal Article}
}
```

[image]

---

And it would be even better if you could use the appropriate citation commands like `\citep` and `\citet`:

```
\documentclass{article}

    \usepackage{natbib}

\begin{document}

    This is the first paper: \citep{RN41}; and this is the second: \cite{RN33}.

    \bibliographystyle{plainnat}
    \bibliography{bibliography_doc_name}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It still does not work. I updated the error that appears in the description above.

Comment: I found out what the problem is, I think that it does not recognise some of my citation, especially the databases'ones. Thank you so much for the help :)